# Render .aspx page without html, body tags

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a test page **Test.aspx**, below is the code i have it in Page_Load function.

```
Response.Write("test");
```

When i execute this page, i can see the html out put "test" along with 
html, body tags in it.

What should i do so that the output only has the text "test", and no body,html tags?

Please suggest.

Comment: Some browsers kinda "invent" html and body tags if you do a "view source". Use fiddler2 to check the real raw output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with this code - based on `ContentType = "text/plain";`

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.Write("Only text is printed");
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.Write("Test");
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have a case that you wont an empty page that you can write just some words, or something else, is better to use a handler .ashx

The handler is not add anything by default, like an .aspx page do, no need to clear anything and you do not spend time to render, then clear as you do with an aspx page.

So the correct way, is to create a handler.